# Good ol' footer trouble

Tags: html, css

So my footer won't stay down. It just appears on the middle of my page. I bet you've seen this question a lot of times but I really need some help since I've read tons of threads and I've tried the general solution outlined here:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

I will link my code and hopefully you can notice why the solution doesn't work for me.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

    <header>
        <title>Heilsa</title>
        <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </header>

<body>
<div id="container">
<img id="bordi" src="taka2.png"/>
    <div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="heim.html">Heim</a></li>
    <li><a href="sida1.html">Hollt Mataræði</a></li>
    <li><a href="sida2.html">Reynslusögur</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="block">
        </div>
        <div id="meginmal">
        <h1>Fyrirsögn</h1>
        <p>A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless it is a place that encourages walls of text. I highly doubt any place does support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one that is. Actually not really lame. You can create a wall of text supporting site, but you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. The wall of text was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would be able to have walls of text. But that community probably wouldn't have actually invented the wall of text. So basically, no one except God and Al Gore knows when or where or how the wall of text existed/was invented. Noobs probably invented, but probably not. Who knows. Walls of texts are usually filled with a lot of useless information and junk. Information and junk can be the same, but only if the information is junk or the junk is information. But who cares. The information/junk inside a wall of text are usually related to wherever the wall of text is located, but the best walls of text, which are actually the most irritating, most eye-bleeding ones, are completely random. Walls of text usually make the reader asplode or have their eyes bleed and fall out of their sockets. A number of people can stand it, but not read them. Actually some people can stand and read them. Those people do not have short attention spans. These are boring and patient people who have no life or have all the time in their hands, which are the same, but not really. The punishment of what making walls of text varies of the strictness of the community. But it doesn't really matter. Nobody cares. Walls of texts should be free of links, different font colors, strange characters, which are those other symbols used in society, and capital letters because it ruins the whole purpose of the infamy of walls of texts. It makes them look dumb and weird. Walls of texts are obviously free of huge spaces and outstanding things like capital letters. Of course, paragraphs should never be in a wall of text. Walls of text are known to create nausea, confusion, head explosion, and others. The others being something I can not think of either because I am lazy or if I do not feel like it or I can not actually think of anything. Like what the fuck? That was a rhetorical question right there. What the fuck? You are actually not requesting a satisfactory answer, you just say that because you try to be funny or you feel like it or if you are pissed off. You must get a proper bitch-slapping to stop making walls of text, but if you are weird then that doesn't apply to you. Walls of text are defeated by deleting them or splitting them into paragraphs. Or some other things that would work but will take hours to think of. People are considered a nuisance if they create walls of text. This might be the end. If you hope this is the end, I am not sure. But if I was not sure then I wouldn't be talking. I should know. Or should I? The best way to make a better and good wall of text is to copy and paste what you previously typed or write. Hey, that reminds me. Walls of text aren't always on the internet! They could be anywhere that is able to produce symbols. D'oh. A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless it is a place that encourages walls of text. I highly doubt any place does support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one that is. Actually not really lame. You can created a wall of text supporting site, but you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. The wall of text was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would be able to have walls of text. But that community probably wouldn't have actually invented the wall of text. So basically, no one except God and Al Gore knows when or where or how the wall of text existed/was invented. Noobs probably invented, but probably not. Who knows. Walls of texts are usually filled with a lot of useless information and junk. Information and junk can be the same, but only if the information is junk or the junk is information.
        </p>
        </div>      
    </div>


    <div id="wrapper">
     <img id="undir" src="undir.png"/>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height:100%;
}

#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
   }

.menu {
width:550px;
height:35px;
font-family:Trajan Pro;
font-size:18px;
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;
text-shadow:3px 2px 3px #333333;
margin-left:1010px;
position:absolute;
top:150px;
}
.menu ul {
    height: auto;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
display: inline;
padding: 20px;
}
.menu a {
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
}
.menu a:hover {
text-shadow: 8px 5px 8px #333333;
font-size:20px;
}

#content {
min-height:100%;
position: relative;
width: 800  px;
height: 800px;
margin-right:200px;
margin-left:200px;
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

#block1 { /*IGNORE THIS. I AM SAVING IT FOR LATER*/
    background: red;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20); /* IE */
    -moz-opacity:0.2; /* Mozilla */
    opacity: 0.2; /* CSS3 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 100%; width:100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin:10px;
}

#meginmal {
padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
text-align: center;
font-size:20px;
border-right: solid;
border-left: solid;
font-family: Trajan Pro;
}

#bordi {
height:100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0%;
padding: 10px;
  }



#wrapper {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Comment: It looks like it appears in the middle of your page because when you position something absolutely, you are taking it out of it's natural flow. You don't need to position it absolutely, since your document is being read from top to bottom and the div that you want at the bottom of your page as your footer is already down there judging by the structure of your HTML. Try removing the absolute position. Give it a clear:both while you're at it so that nothing appears on its sides. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Also... please change `<header>` to `<head>`.

Comment: Is there any way to have it stay on bottom now matter how long my content is? (and not have my content go through my footer).

Comment: New problem in a picture: http://i.imgur.com/1yONND6.png

(Should I make a new question since the problem is new, or?)

Answer (score 2):

From your code, you have footer as id wrapper
Change the position from absolute to fixed

```
#wrapper {
     position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: This changes things, but what happens is that when I scroll, the footer scrolls too. I want the footer to be at the bottom of the page and not scroll with it.

Comment: This is the line:

#wrapper {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

It still scrolls.

Comment: position:fixed; seems to make it scroll.. ?